# An initialization is affecting code that has no connection to the initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

In the following code, I thought the last loop would print `1 2 3 4` four times, once on each new line. The code prints `1 3 2 1` instead of `1 2 3 4` four times.

- The problem goes away if I change the type of `{1, 3, 2, 1}` from `double` to `int`.
- The problem goes away if I take `double line[] = {1, 3, 2, 1}` out of the if-else block.

I just can't understand how the initialization of the variable `double line[]` is affecting the assignment of `vector <double *> v`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector <double*> v;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        double line[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        v.push_back(new double[4]);
        v[std::abs(v.size()) - 1] = line;
    }
    if(0 > 1)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        double line[] = {1, 3, 2, 1};
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            std::cout << v[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: [Your code doesn't even compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d184f881f81ec1b)

Comment: Made a mistake while typing the post. Sorry. I've edited it to reflect the correct code.

Comment: [Still doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/741d46e34e5442d6)

Comment: `double line[] = {1, 3, 2, 1};` declares a new variable in that scope that is not connected to the other variable with the same name in any way, then that scope end and so does that variable. All your first loop does is create a memory leak.

Comment: your first `line` is destroyed after each iteration and therefore `v[x]` is a dangling pointer, yielding undefined behavior

Comment: @SudipKunda `v[std::abs(v.size()) - 1]` is bizzare.

Comment: `std::vector<std::array<double, 4>>` -- That's what you should be using, not `std::vector<double *>` and strange code using / misusing pointers.

Comment: [See this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ddd821ae0d4f5b61)

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        double line[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};      
        v.push_back(new double[4]);
        v[std::abs(v.size()) - 1] = line;
    }
```

all you have is memory leak + undefined behavior.

You are creating `line` in the stack, as the end of each iterator, it goes out of scope, which means, you are not doing what you intended to.  Accessing, them latter gives you UB. 
Secondly, you are creating each time `new double[4]` in heap, which you have not managed/ deallocated latter, resulting in memory leak!

You might wanna do this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

std::vector <std::array<int, 4>> v;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) v.emplace_back(std::array<int, 4>{ 1, 2, 3, 4 });
```

will give a vector of arrays (2 dimensional) with a 4x4 dimension.
And acces them using range based-loop:

```
for (const std::array<int, 4>& row : v)
{
    for (const int element : row) std::cout << element << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

---

However, it looks like you are doing an assignement, where you can must deal with `std::vector <int*> v;` way. If so, an extra de-allocation is required to free the memory you created with `new` keyword.

```
std::vector <int*> v;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    v.emplace_back(new int[4]{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }); // create and store to vector

for (const int* row : v)
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    // do print

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)  delete[] v[i];   // free the memory using delete
```

However, I would suggest using [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers), as you are leaning C++ not C.
For instance, the above code can be wrtitten using [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

```
std::vector <std::unique_ptr<int[]>> v;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    v.emplace_back(std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[4]{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }));

for (const std::unique_ptr<int[]>& row : v)
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        std::cout << row[j] << " ";
 // no mannual memory management is required.
```

Comment: `std::vector<std::array<double,4>>` is a better option.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You are right, as the size is fixed. Let me update with that.

Comment: Also, by using `std::array`, the OP's code barely has to change.  All that needs to be done is totally remove `line[]` from the code and use the brace initializer directly.